# How to implement Signin with apple in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui, apple-sign-in

I'm trying to add Apple Signin in a swiftUI application without success.
Problem is that the login and scope screen is shown but when finishing the flow the delegate methods are NOT called.
The button class

```
import SwiftUI
import AuthenticationServices
struct QuickSignInWithApple: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIViewType {
        return ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton()
        // or just use UIViewType()  Not recommanded though.
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

The View model

```
import AuthenticationServices
 
import SwiftUI
class SignInWithAppleVIewModel: NSObject, ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {
    
    
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController,
                                 didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        switch authorization.credential {
        case let appleIdCredential as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential:
            if let _ = appleIdCredential.email, let _ = appleIdCredential.fullName {
                // Apple has authorized the use with Apple ID and password
                registerNewUser(credential: appleIdCredential)
            } else {
                // User has been already exist with Apple Identity Provider
                signInExistingUser(credential: appleIdCredential)
            }
            break
            
        case let passwordCredential as ASPasswordCredential:
            print("\n ** ASPasswordCredential ** \n")
            signinWithUserNamePassword(credential: passwordCredential)
            break
            
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
        print("\n -- ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate -\(#function) -- \n")
        print(error)
    }
    private func registerNewUser(credential: ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential) {
        // API Call - Pass the email, user full name, user identity provided by Apple and other details.
        // Give Call Back to UI
        print(credential.email ?? "Email not available.")
        print(credential.fullName ?? "fullname not available")
        print(credential.fullName?.givenName ?? "givenName not available")
        print(credential.fullName?.familyName ?? "Familyname not available")
        print(credential.user)  // This is a user identifier
        print(credential.identityToken?.base64EncodedString() ?? "Identity token not available") //JWT Token
        print(credential.authorizationCode?.base64EncodedString() ?? "Authorization code not available")
    }
    
    private func signInExistingUser(credential: ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential) {
        // API Call - Pass the user identity, authorizationCode and identity token
        // Give Call Back to UI
        print(credential.email ?? "Email not available.")
        print(credential.fullName ?? "fullname not available")
        print(credential.fullName?.givenName ?? "givenName not available")
        print(credential.fullName?.familyName ?? "Familyname not available")
        print(credential.user)  // This is a user identifier
        print(credential.identityToken?.base64EncodedString() ?? "Identity token not available") //JWT Token
        print(credential.authorizationCode?.base64EncodedString() ?? "Authorization code not available")
    }
    
    private func signinWithUserNamePassword(credential: ASPasswordCredential) {
        // API Call - Sign in with Username and password
        // Give Call Back to UI
        print("\n ** ASPasswordCredential ** \n")
        print(credential.user)  // This is a user identifier
        print(credential.password) //The password
    }

}
```

The in my LoginView I have the following

```
//before the body
    private func showAppleLoginView() {
        let appleViewModel:SignInWithAppleVIewModel = SignInWithAppleVIewModel()
        // 1. Instantiate the AuthorizationAppleIDProvider
        let provider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        // 2. Create a request with the help of provider - ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest
        let request = provider.createRequest()
        // 3. Scope to contact information to be requested from the user during authentication.
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        // 4. A controller that manages authorization requests created by a provider.
        let controller = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        // 5. Set delegate to perform action
        controller.delegate = appleViewModel

        // 6. Initiate the authorization flows.
        controller.performRequests()
    }

 
                    
    QuickSignInWithApple()
    .border(Color.black, width: 2)
    .background(Color.black)
    .cornerRadius(25)
    .frame(width: 280, height: 60, alignment: .center)
    .onTapGesture(perform: showAppleLoginView)
```

So although the delegate is set to the ViewModel it is never called

Comment: You aren’t showing enough for an [mre], but right away I see that your delegate is going out of scope immediately. You need to hold a reference to it.

Comment: How do I hold a reference

Comment: How about making SignInWithAppleVIewModel an ObservableObject and storing it with `@StateObject`?

Comment: Just use the SwiftUI button https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/signinwithapplebutton

Comment: Is login flow working at all? By doc you are not setting controller.presentationContextProvider and func presentationAnchor(for controller: ASAuthorizationController) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
        return viewController.view.window!;
    } See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/implementing_user_authentication_with_sign_in_with_apple